# How can I load an Image that was converted into a base64 string by Image.toString?

Tags: python, simplecv

I'm trying to get the following example to work:

```
import SimpleCV as scv

lenna = scv.Image('lenna')
scv.Image(lenna.toString()).show()
```

The above code produces an `IOError` as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-225589a7ddf6> in <module>()
----> 1 scv.Image(lenna.toString()).show()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/ImageClass.pyc in __init__(self, source, camera, colorSpace, verbose, sample, cv2image, webp)
   1071                     self._bitmap = cv.LoadImage(self.filename, iscolor=cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
   1072                 except:
-> 1073                     self._pil = pil.open(self.filename).convert("RGB")
   1074                     self._bitmap = cv.CreateImageHeader(self._pil.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
   1075                     cv.SetData(self._bitmap, self._pil.tostring())

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in open(fp, mode)
   1986     if isStringType(fp):
   1987         filename = fp
-> 1988         fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
   1989     else:
   1990         filename = ""

IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long:  [...]  # base64 string excluded because it's long as all hell
```

I also tried decoding the string first, to no avail:

```
import SimpleCV as scv

lenna = scv.Image('lenna')
scv.Image(lenna.toString().decode('base64')).show()
```

Which produces a similar error, albeit with a much smaller reported filename.

What gives?  How am I supposed to accomplish this?

**Edit:** It should also be noted that simply decoding the bytestring, i.e. `lenna.toString.decode('base64')` does not work, either.  I just get another base64-looking string.

Comment: It looks like scv.Image() is expecting a filename. Assuming that `lenna = scv.Image('lenna')` works alright, can't you just do this: `lenna.show()`?

Comment: @MarkkuK., the goal here is to load a simplecv image that has previously been output as a string with the `toString` method.

Comment: If there is no method available to create an Image from a string, then you could try writing the string to a file, and reading that: `f = open("tmpfile","wb"); f.write(lenna.toString()); f.close(); scv.Image("tmpfile").show()`

Comment: @MarkkuK. Yes, I also tried that but the image seems to be saved with an improper header.